# C# Class Fullname ends with +<>c. Why?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I debug my application and have a Class Input, but in the Debugger there are two, see Screenshot.
There is only one class Input, no InnerClass or something else.

What is this?

[image: Double Class]

Comment: The compiler generates additional classes e.g. for implemeting async state machines or closures in LINQ expressions.

Comment: .NET Core doesn't have such classes. Judging by the names, it looks like you're using MatBlazor in a Unit test. Blazor itself generates classes for pages and components. If you use bUnit, you've got even more generated classes

Comment: That doesn't *look* like a compiler-generated type -- it's not a naming scheme I recognise. It's more likely to be a type generated at runtime using System.Reflection.Emit, I think. It's normal to add characters which are valid in IL but not in C#, such as `<` and `>`, to ensure there are no collisions with types the user has defined in C#

Comment: Note that the duplicate just makes it clear that what you're seeing is **not** a compiler-generated type -- but doesn't help identify what did generate it

Comment: I guess the only thing we can conclude from that name is that it isn't a type declared with normal C# source code.